# How to solve the error in simple To Do List

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making simple To-do-list in JavaScript but I'm stuck with an error. Don't know why error is coming? Please help me.

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="eie">Title</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eie">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exd">Descrition</label>
   <textarea name="txtara" id="exd" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
<script>
   let btn = document.getElementById(`btn`)
   let sub = btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
     console.log('updating list...')
     let doc = document.getElementById('eie').value
     let doc1 = document.getElementById('exd').value
     if (localStorage.getItem('filejson')==null) {
       let localjsonarray = []
       localjsonarray.push([doc,doc1])
       let set = localStorage.setItem('filejson', JSON.stringify(localjsonarray))
      }else{
       let getting = localStorage.getItem('filejson')
       localjsonarray = JSON.parse(getting);
       localjsonarray.push([doc,doc1])
       let set =localStorage.setItem('filejson',JSON.stringify(localjsonarray))
     }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please state what is the error. Also your code is not complete, its missing closing tags as far as I can see.

Comment: Can you share what the error is ? Is it a syntax error or a logic error ?

Comment: Delete `;` before `else`.

Comment: It's a logic error